# Javascript converting to blob undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am having an undefined value when I tried to convert my canvas to a blob. I have this code below which works fine, but when I tried to move the console log below to the function then it gives me undefined.

Here is the working code:

```
    const handleSave = (params) => {
    
    let previewUrl;
    previewCanvasRef.current.toBlob(
      (blob) => {
        previewUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log(previewUrl);                  
      },
      'image/png',
      1
    );
}
```

when I tried to make the console log below. then It gives me an undefiend value:

```
const handleSave = (params) => {
    
    let previewUrl;
    previewCanvasRef.current.toBlob(
      (blob) => {
        previewUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        
      },
      'image/png',
      1
    );

    console.log(previewUrl);
}
```

Here is what I've tried but error:

```
const handleSave = (params) => {
    
    let previewUrl;
    previewCanvasRef.current.toBlob(
      async (blob) => {
        previewUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);        
      },
      'image/png',
      1
    ).then((res) => console.log(res));  
}
```

Comment: no, nothing is changing it back to undefined ... your second piece of code is logging previewUrl before it is being set - because ... asyncrhony

Comment: First parameter to toBlob function is a callback. This will work in asynchronous way. In second case console will get logged immediately (before calling the callback) hence it will not work.

Comment: how can i set it with the exact value? sorry for that. Im a beginner in js  @JaromandaX

Comment: you are setting it ... `previewUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);` ... you need to do whatever you need with it in that callback

Comment: Do your console within your callback.

Comment: @JaromandaX may i know how can i make this async function ?

Comment: it is an async function - and you can't change it to sync - because time travel doesn't exist

Comment: @JaromandaX may i know where can i put the async function ?

Comment: what async function? the callback is called back asynchronously

Comment: does `previewCanvasRef.current.toBlob` function return a Promise? you can't just tack `.then` onto anything and expect it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the syntax you're looking for to turn this into an asynchronous function:

```js
const canvasToBlob = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  previewCanvasRef.current.toBlob(resolve, 'image/png', 1);
});

const handleSave = async () => {
  const blob = await canvasToBlob();
  const previewURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}
```

Because `async`/`await` is just syntax sugar for wrapping Promises, if you want to create your own `async` function out of a traditional callback-style function, you would need to use Promises manually (since you can't `return` to exit the `canvasToBlob` function from *within* the callback of `toBlob`, as that would simply return the `toBlob` method).

So, here, we simply tell `toBlob` to use `resolve` as its callback: a Promise's `resolve(arg)` is equivalent to an `async` function's `return arg` (and `reject(err)` is equivalent to `throw err`). In this case, the `Blob` being passed to the `toBlob` callback is `arg`. We can now use this function with `async`/`await` syntax sugar.

Just keep in mind that, when you're using asynchronous functions, your *entire* chain needs to be in `async` mode: every function down the line that depends on this blob will need to be either wrapped with `async`/`await` syntax or `.then`'d—because a **synchronous function cannot depend on an asynchronous value**. In the real world, all that means is that you gotta remember to define your functions as `async`.

[This page from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) will provide you with some more detailed readings on asynchronous functions in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to handle asynchrony is with Promises

```
const handleSave = (params) =>
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    previewCanvasRef.current.toBlob(
      (blob) => resolve(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)),
      "image/png",
      1
    )
  );
```

use it like

```
handleSave(......).then(blob => {
  // do things here
});
```

or using async/await - must be inside an async function to do so

```
async function () {
  const blob = await handleSave(.....);
  // do things with blob
}
```

Comment: hello I editted my question.. Can you please check my above code

Comment: @DarkVader191919- You can't just tack `.then` on to any function and expect it to work - that's not how programming works - I've shown you in this answer how to do it

Comment: because i have another function to be executed inside the handleSave..

Comment: I want only the function inside to have the value that i want. then execute another function inside the handleSave

Comment: const handleSave = (params) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => previewCanvasRef.current.toBlob((blob) => {
    resolve(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  }, 'image/png',1);
} 

is error

Comment: is error you way? what error is?

Comment: oh, yeah, had a `;` that shouldn't have been there - tidied up that function now